# TypeScript - Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'

Tags: typescript

Here is my code:

```js
var a:number;
a = 4;

var myArr: number[];
myArr = [1,2,3];
myArr.push(1);

a = myArr.pop();
```

When I compile with "module" (in my tsconfig.json file) set to "system" or "amd" to allow me to bundle the output into an "outFile" location, I get this error:

> hello-world.ts:23:1 - error TS2322: Type 'number | undefined' is not
>   assignable to type 'number'.   Type 'undefined' is not assignable to
>   type 'number'.
>
> a = myArr.pop();

Where is it getting the "undefined" type from? Also, how do I resolve this error without setting "strict" to false (in my tsconfig.json)?

Comment: `.pop()` returns `undefined` if the array is empty.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Array.prototype.pop()` returns type number or undefined. That's where number undefined comes from.

When you perform pop() on an object, a number is returned when array.length > 0, and undefined is returned if array.length = 0.

You should either check if `myArr.pop() !== undefined`

-or-

`a: number | undefined;`

Comment: I have !== undefined check in place and still get that error :/

Comment: Any solutions to the problem raised by @jayarjo?

Comment: @Nyxynyx `a = myArr.pop() as number`;