# type 'Book' unassignable to type 'Book'

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

i am trying to learn how to use angular and typescript, i was following a video up to a point where he was trying to make a method (getBookId) which should take a book id and then check in an array and return its information when there's a book with the same id.

[this is the repository.model.ts with method thats causing the error it says:
Type 'Book | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Book'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Book'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhPnc.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript - Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56638961/typescript-type-number-undefined-is-not-assignable-to-type-number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type should be `Book | undefined`, since `find` method can return undefined if book with the match is not found.

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) for reference.

```
getBookId(id: Number): Book | undefined {
  return this.books.find(book => book.id === id);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you have only stated your the typescript error and not what your problem is, I am assuming you want to know why you are getting this error and want to fix it.

```
Type 'Book | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Book'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Book'
```

The error is coming from `Array.prototype.find()` method. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find),

> The find() method returns the value of the first element in the
> provided array that satisfies the provided testing function. If no
> values satisfy the testing function, undefined is returned.

From, [lib.es2015.core.d.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/lib/lib.es2015.core.d.ts)

> find(predicate: (value: T, index: number, obj: T[]) => unknown,
> thisArg?: any): T | undefined;

In your case T = Book, so find() will either return an object of Type Book or undefined, but your getBookId() method returns Book. So if find() method returns undefined typescript would not be able to convert it to Book, that is what the error is actually conveying.

How to fix the error:

1. Non-null assertion operator

   return this.books.find(book => book.id == id)!
2. Update return type of the calling function

   getBook(id: number): Book | undefined
3. Typecast to Book

   return this.books.find(book => book.id == id) as Book
4. Turn off strictNullChecks (not recommended)
   This is not recommended as it can cause difficult to track problems.
   Read more about it at [strictNullChecks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks)